# Matrix size error when try to predict number from image

Tags: python-3.x, keras, prediction, tf.keras

i'm having some troubles while coding my first NN program.
I basically would like to draw a numeber in a canvas and give it to a NN that should show the "recognized" number.

```
#create the NN, train with mnist and load img saved from canvas
def Analizza():

    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape= x_train.shape[1:]))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
    model.save('modello_numeri.model')

    getter(c)

    width = 28
    height = 28

    img = Image.open(immagine_salvata)
    img = img.resize((width,height), Image.BICUBIC)
    img.save(immagine_salvata)

    img = PIL.Image.open("immagine.jpg").convert("L")
    img_ar = np.array(img)

    img_ar_norm = tf.keras.utils.normalize(img_ar, axis=1)

    plt.imshow(img_ar, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()  

    #make prediction
    predizione = model.predict(img_ar_norm, batch_size=None)
    risposta = np.argmax(predizione[0])

    print(risposta)

    #risultato = tk.Label(window, text=risposta, font=("Helvetica",57))
    #risultato.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="E")
```

this part gives me these errors:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File >"C:\Users\Massimo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
>      return self.func(*args)
>    File "c:/Users/Massimo/AppVisualCode/disegno.py", line 91, in Analizza
>       predizione = model.predict(img_ar_norm, batch_size=None)
>    File "C:\Users\Massimo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1113, in predict
>       self, x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
>     File "C:\Users\Massimo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 329, in model_iteration
>       batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
>     File "C:\Users\Massimo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3076, in **call**
>       run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
>     File "C:\Users\Massimo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in **call**
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "C:\Users\Massimo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [28,28], In[1]: [784,128]
>            [[{{node MatMul}}]]

I understood there should be a problem with the size of the matrix expected for the prediction but why? i'm saving the image, resize it as 28x28, black and white and than open as a np array like if it was x_train[0]

Thank you
Max

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Comment: In plain English, this means get rid of all the irrelevant stuff on `tkinter`, widgets etc and post a **minimal** example based on your `Analizza()` function, which produces the error...

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for the bad post, i edited it and i hope it's more readable now.

Comment: can you please help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225332/matrix-size-incompatible